# How to create stereotypes in emf meta-model

Tags: eclipse-emf

I want to know please, how can we create stereotypes in EMF. More precisely, I created a meta-model but I could not add  stereotypes.

I tried to install EMF profiles, but I couldn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, EMF does not support profiles/stereotypes, which is a UML concept.